# how to convert raw mp3 binary into blob url and play it in audio tag

Tags: javascript, websocket, blob

What im doing is sending mp3 data through websockets as base64 strings and decoding it on browser side now what im trying to do is turn that raw data into a blob and play it in an audio tag but i dont know how can you help also decoding base64 strings is laggy is there a better way

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/rn/g,"n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}

    var AudioType = "audio/mp3";
    var protocol = "ws://";
    var host = "127.0.0.1";
    var port = 4446;
    var uri = protocol + host + ":" + port + "/"
    var ws = new WebSocket(uri);
    ws.onopen = function() {
        console.log("Connected");
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({"reqID3":1}));
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({"init":1}))
    }
    ws.onmessage = function(e){
        var js = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if (js.id3) {
            document.getElementById("bitrate").innerHTML = js.id3.bitrate;
            document.getElementById("length").innerHTML = js.id3.length;
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = js.id3.title;
        }
        if (js.buffer) {
            //console.log(js.buffer)
            var b = Base64.decode(js.buffer)
            console.log(b)
            var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
            audio.type = AudioType;
            audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(b);


        }
    }
    ws.onclose = function() {
        ws.close()
```

Comment: You've added numerous layers of complexity.  Why are you doing what you're doing?  If you're sending data in one direction (either from the client to the server, or from the server to the client), you don't need Web Sockets.  Even if you were to use Web Sockets, they support binary transfer so there's no need to go through that 33% overhead in size, and all the extra CPU.  Even after all of that, there's no reason to do these big MP3 chunks when you could just stream the data straight through.  If you just used HTTP normally, you could throw away all this code and use an `<audio>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert it to raw . HTML5 Audio already supports base64 as a URL :

`<audio controls src="data:audio/mp3;base64, ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Audiocontext` from [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer). Use `AudioContext.createBuffer()` for raw data and then it can be played by being passed into an `AudioBufferSourceNode`. You can also use the `decodeAudioData()` method to use an audio file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of data is "js.buffer"? But if it is base64 encoded already, just prefix it like @Ashraf said as:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.type = AudioType;
audio.src = "data:audio/mpeg;base64," + js.buffer;
// audio.src = "data:" + AudioType + ";base64," + js.buffer;
```

> FYI: Modern browsers have built-in base64 encode/decode.

```
Use:
   atob() - decode base64
   btoa() - encode base64
```