# live stream mp3 with websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, live-streaming

How can I stream an mp3 live via websockets

```
var AudioType = "audio/mp3";
var protocol = "ws://";
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 4446;
var uri = protocol + host + ":" + port + "/"
var ws = new WebSocket(uri);
ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log("Connected");
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({"reqID3":1}));
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({"init":1}))
}
ws.onmessage = function(e){
    var js = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (js.id3) {
        document.getElementById("bitrate").innerHTML = js.id3.bitrate;
        document.getElementById("length").innerHTML = js.id3.length;
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = js.id3.title;
    }
    if (js.buffer) {
        //console.log(js.buffer)
        var b = js.buffer
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        audio.type = AudioType;
        audio.src = "data:audio/mp3;base64,"+b


    }
}
ws.onclose = function() {
    ws.close()
}
```

notice the `audio.src` it loads base64 data 4096 in length problem is stream doesn't continue to play it restarts everytime a new base64 string is loaded is there a work around is it even possible to do this with websockets

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but first answer my comment on your question from yesterday:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/51805547/362536  I can save you quite a great deal of hassle if you can explain *specifically* what you're trying to do.  If you must use WebSockets, use MediaSource Extensions.  But, I have a hunch that's not necessary.

Comment: okay there's the server and source client the source client takes the raw binary data and turns it into base64 string at the length of 4096 that then gets sent to the server the server then waits for clients (browser) to send the init then it will begin sending the base64 chunks to the browser the browser takes those chunks and turns it into music im trying to emulate this https://github.com/tinker1234/PyCaster but In websockets but I can't figure out how to get it to play without stopping while keeping it live

Comment: Base64 is not what you want at all.  As I said in your other question, you're adding a ton of overhead.  Additionally, there is no reason to even use Web Sockets.  You can skip that whole layer entirely and use HTTP Progressive.  Once using regular HTTP, you can simply use an `<audio>` tag, or for anything particularly long-running (days), you can use MSE.  If you're interested in licensing some code already written for this, feel free to contact me at brad@audiopump.co.

Comment: if your meaning something like shoutcast and icecast does by sending raw audio data to a mount point ive done that with PyCaster I was trying to do it with websockets but I cant figure it out unless you mean something else

Comment: What's your reason for using websockets?  If the issue is that your source client is in a browser, you need to basically proxy the websocket payload from the source client to regular HTTP clients.  (Or better yet, just receive the data and ship it off to Icecast and let it handle the clients.  There are *many* quirks in streaming clients, particularly around chunked transfer encoding that need to be accounted for.)